# How do I delete duplicate columns after unmerging cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am extracting reports fro BO into excel, and the export results in merged cells. The BO report is date drive the width of columns varies, so merged cells today, do not match merged cells tomorrow, which is why hard coding cells is not an option.

I have a piece of code that does successfully unmerge the columns, but the result is duplicate columns that I need to delete. I keep getting an erro that method object is not defined.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim rows_used As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim ws_1 As Workbook

rows_used = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To 35
    For j = 1 To rows_used
        If Cells(j, i).MergeCells Then
            Cells(j, i).UnMerge
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To 35
    k = 0
    Do
        If Range(Cells(1, i)).Value = Range(Cells(1, i + 1)).Value Then
            Range(Cells(1, i + 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Loop Until k = 3
Next i
```

End Sub

I have tired tried just using `Cells(1,i)` without the `Range()` tag, but that also failed.

Columns Before the UnMerge

[image: Columns before the UnMerge]

Columns After the UnMerge

[image: Columns After UnMerge]

Answer (score 0):

Your range reference in the second loop in not correctly formatted. This worked for me

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Dim rows_used As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer

   Dim ws_1 As Workbook

rows_used = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To 35
    For j = 1 To rows_used
        If Cells(j, i).MergeCells Then
            Cells(j, i).UnMerge
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To 35
    k = 0
    Do
        If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i + 1).Value Then
            Cells(1, i + 1).EntireColumn.Delete
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Loop Until k = 3
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: this was my first version. It crashes my excel. It sends excel into "Not Responding" on open. That was why I tried the 'Ranges' and posted on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

If comes down to the fact I don't have an Else in my If statement. The lack of Else prevented the k from being incremented.

Thanks @Adach1979 for suggesting I go back to cells.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To 35
    For j = 1 To counter
        If Cells(j, i).MergeCells Then
            Cells(j, i).UnMerge
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To 35
    k = 0
    Do
        If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i + 1).Value Then
            Cells(1, i + 1).EntireColumn.Delete
            k = k + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until k = 5
Next i
```